# Promise: avoid forking/splitting and chain first this then do this

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

Here's the code as it is now, promise chain is the same it was before. I've started to attempt to use Promise.all() to move away from the antiPattern

```
(function(){
'use strict';

function DOMObj(){
    var that = this;

    that.items = [];

    that.getitems = function(url) {
        return new Promise (resolve => {
                $.getJSON(url, function (response) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.sales.length; i++) {

                        that.items.push(new ProductObj(response.sales[i], i));

                    }
                    resolve();
                });
            }
        )
    };

    that.updateProductHTML = function(){
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            for( var i = 0; i < that.items.length; i++){

                that.items[i].updateHTML();

            }
            resolve();
        })
    };

    that.updateDOM = function() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            var thisHTML = '';

            for( var i = 0; i < that.items.length; i++) {

                if (i % 3 === 0 ) {
                    thisHTML += "<div class='row'>";
                    // console.log("START");
                }

                thisHTML += that.items[i].htmlView;

                if ((i % 3 === 2) || i === (that.items.length - 1) ) {
                    thisHTML += "</div>";
                     console.log("FINISH");
                }
            }
            $("#content").append(thisHTML);
            resolve();
        })
    }
}

function ProductObj(product, i) {
    var that = this;

    that.photo = product.photo;
    that.title = product.title;
    that.subtitle = product.subTitle;
    that.url = product.url;

    that.htmlView = "";
    that.index = i;


    that.updateHTML = function() {
        $.get('template.html', function(template){
            that.htmlView = template.replace('{image}', that.photo)
                .replace('{title}', that.title)
                .replace('{subtitle}', that.subtitle)
                .replace('{url}', that.url);

             console.log(that.index + ' product has worked through html')
        })
    };
}
var myView = new DOMObj();

myView.getitems('data.json')
    .then(
        myView.updateProductHTML
    )
    .then(
        myView.updateDOM()
    )
    .then(() =>{
        $('.deleteButton').click(() => {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });

//Promise.all([ myView.getitems('data.json'), myView.updateProductHTML, myView.updateDOM, () => {$('.deleteButton').click(() => {
    //$(this).parent().remove();
//})}])

})();
```

so far the code runs in this order `getItems => updateProductHTML` then `updateDOM` runs with it, the last code I'm attempting to add is a click event on a button which needs to run last apparently

Comment: Please show us your actual code. Don't say "*my promises are set up as such*" and then show us horribly broken (pseudo?) code.

Comment: That `this.updateHTML` looks asynchronous, yes, but it actually needs to **`return` the `$.get` promise** to be useful!

Comment: That's the code skipper

Comment: Well, but it's the code you have problems with, so please don't skip it.

Comment: No thats the actual code

Comment: Oh, sorry for the misunderstanding then. But that cannot work, you never *call* `resolve()`. `updateProductHTML` and `updateDOM` would never run, though you claimed they do? Regardless, please add the code of `getData`, as that's the asynchronous one that you need to fix. Just calling it from inside the promise constructor doesn't help anything, you need to actually fulfill the promise asynchronously.

Comment: where isn't resolve called? it's in every promise

Comment: In the code you posted, you have `resolve;` not `resolve()`.

Comment: ah, you're looking at the old code. The updates were my attempt at keeping an archive of some sort if this is looked up later. I'm just gonna paste the code as it is now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your functions to **return a promise that will be resolved when the callback function has finished**:

```
this.updateHTML = function() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        $.get('product-template.html', function(template) {
            this.htmlView = template.replace('{image}', this.photo)
                .replace('{string1}', this.string1)
                .replace('{string2}', this.string2)
                .replace('{url}', this.URL)
                .replace('{class}', this.class);
            resolve();
        });
    });
};
```

Same for `getData()`.

---

Then you should be able to easily chain the steps:

```
getData().then(updateHTML).then(updateDOM);
```

Comment: Ok with that setup i get getData => updateProductHTML and updateDOM at the same time.  I can't drop the promise into the updateHTML as its inside of another for loop so the thenable can't reach it. I put it on my for loop but it's not running right

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Comment: @Bergi Interesting read. This applies mainly to `getData` though, as a potential `fetch` already returns a promise, not to `updateHTML`, correct?

Comment: Your `updateHTML` is using a promise - `$.get(…)`. It does take optional callbacks, but always returns a (jQuery) promise. You can simply `omit` it and even put that callback in a `.then(…)` call. If you don't want to use jQuery promises, [just wrap it in a `Promise.resolve(…)`.